# How to handle fix-like answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6990484/1469208), an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990682/1469208) to it and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514828/1469208), which I call a *fix-like* answers (correct me, if it is bad).

It goes like that:

1. Someone asks.
2. Someone answers (*answer A*).
3. Some third person finds *answer A* not working, but instead of editing or giving comment, places own *answer B*.
4. *Answer A*'s author (or anyone else) finds out, that *answer A* isn't working, finds out, that *answer B* is working and edits *answer A*, so it now looks nearly exactly as *answer B*.

And we end up with a pretty mess (at least in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6990484/1469208)). If you only do a quick browse of answers, you can get the feeling, that *answer B* is a direct duplicate of *answer A*. You only can figure out, how things really are, by reading through comments.

How should we handle such situations? What should we do with answers, that should never be given and which author should actually edit the "original" answer?

Comment: There's a business plan in there when coupled with questions in tags that suffer from the FGITW problem: 1. Post something that does look like an answer so as to avoid an NAA flag, and reduce edit needs in step 3. 2. Wait until someone who actually knows what they are talking about posts a correct answer. 3. Edit your answer to fix it on the basis of the correct answer. 4. Profit! I've seen this happen a number of times and is the reason I thoroughly despise the edit grace period. (I don't care if someone can see that the first version of my post looks like something only a Vogon could love.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're looking for a black-and-white answer when there isn't one. Sometimes the error in answer A is tiny, and commenting "you seem to have a and b flipped" or "shouldn't you also increment i after you make a find?" is the right thing to do. Other times, the error in A is far too large for a comment alone to be right, and the person who spots the error should add their own answer.

**Important sidenote:** it is never right to edit an answer to fix an error. Editing is for readability and clarity. The fact your edits no longer need to be reviewed does not bestow the ability to edit to fix errors: it means the system believes you have learned not to edit to fix errors.

So step 1, there's a spectrum of wrongness in the first answer that means sometimes posting a new answer is the right thing to do, and sometimes posting a comment is the right thing to do. Then we have the matter of what happens to answer A. Should it sit there being wrong for all time, possibly leading future readers down the wrong path, because you think anything else would unfairly reward someone who was wrong once? NO. It should be fixed by its author into something right. (Not by anyone else, because that would be editing to fix an error.) If the original author makes those fixes, **the system works** because a bad answer has gone away and been replaced with a good answer.

Once a question has two very similar answers, what should you do? Upvote them both and then stop worrying about it. It's not anyone's job to be the reputation-fairness-and-deservedness police. You worry that answer B, which was first to be correct, will be underrewarded compared to answer A which appears to be first to be correct? **Stop handing out upvotes based on timestamps**, and don't encourage others to do that either. Upvote good answers and when a question has two of them, relax and enjoy that bounty of information sharing the site has created.

Who knows? One of the two answerers may choose to delete their answer if they don't like the duplication. But there's no need for the rest of us to worry about that. Nearly identical answers happen all the time just from people typing at the same time. If you feel the need to stamp them out, close the kind of question that attracts those. Don't worry about editing wrong into right - that's something that should happen.

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation. Yours "_Important sidenote_" part explains a lot and fixes certain mistakes in my way of viewing review process. Thx!

Answer (score 7):

Nothing. Both answers are valid.

Person B did the right thing in this case, posting a new answer. The code of someone else's answer should not be substantially edited; the only acceptable edits are typos and other small fixes.

Even in those cases, i think it's OK for the other person to post their own answer.

If person A then fixes their answer, good for them.

In any case, it's not like we don't often get a few nearly identical answers on easy questions, and no one makes the answerers delete them.

Comment: I'm quite surprised with your answer. I've seen only a few examples of the case disputed here and many, many more, where an error in answer was discovered and then that answer was edited (by author or someone else) instead of giving the other answer. I thought, that flag that flags, that edit clearly conflicts with author's intensions is only for really "brute" changes. I thought, that we want answers with working, optionally corrected code, not with twin-like-answers.

Comment: Most reviewers, me included, will reject edits that change code, unless it is trivial edits of the type i said.